# Azure Storage CloudTable Using read-only SAS key returns 403 Forbidden

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, http-status-code-403

I am trying to use a read-only SAS key to connect to an Azure CloudTable and query. I use this exact same SAS in Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer with no issues at all.

I have tried a couple of ways (derived from this site), but I always get 403 Forbidden:

Method 1:

```
string _SAS = "https://[myaccount].table.core.windows.net/?sv=2017-07-29&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rlp&se=2019-02-22T03:14:04Z&st=2018-02-21T19:14:04Z&spr=https&sig=[mySignature]";
StorageCredentials accountSAS = new StorageCredentials(_devSAS);
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(accountSAS, "[MyAccount]", endpointSuffix: null, useHttps: true);
CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
CloudTable tableClientTable = tableClient.GetTableReference("[MyTableName]");

TableQuery<AccessErrorLog> rangeQuery = new TableQuery<AccessErrorLog>().Where(
    TableQuery.CombineFilters(
        TableQuery.CombineFilters(
            TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, AspNetCompaniesId),
            TableOperators.And,
            TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate("Timestamp", QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual, date)
        ),
        TableOperators.And,
        TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("ProgramSource", QueryComparisons.Equal, ProgramSource)
    )
);

foreach (AccessErrorLog entity in tableClientTable.ExecuteQuery(rangeQuery))
{
    LogInformationRecords.Add(entity.ErrorMessage);
}
```

Method 2:

```
StorageCredentials accountSAS = new StorageCredentials(_devSAS);
CloudTable tableClientTable = new CloudTable(new Uri("https://[MyAccount].table.core.windows.net/[MyTableName]"), accountSAS);

// Same query and foreach as above...
```

If I use an actual connection string (ie `string _devKey = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=[MyAccount];AccountKey=[MyAccountKey]";` and use `CloudStorageAccount.Parse(_devKey);` the query and execution works just fine without 403 error.

Because I can use the SAS in Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer without issue, and I can use the actual connection string in my app without any issues, I can only think I am missing something very obvious.

Edit: I forgot to mention the SAS claims to have "Read, List, Process" permissions when I use it in Azure Storage Explorer.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can see that multiple factors may result in the issue you are experiencing. One is the use of Service SAS vs Account SAS. **Service SAS** allows you to use the SAS only in one specific storage product(ex: Blobs only) rather than all products, **Account SAS** allows you to uses SAS for different products in storage: Blobs, Tables, Queues etc...
More info can be found [**here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1#types-of-shared-access-signatures) . If you are using the Service SAS for a specific product, then trying to use Tables, it won't allow you to do so.

An additional factor would be the SAS account must have the Query Tables operation (to read only) for this to work. More on how to construct the URl for Account SAS Tables can be found [**here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/constructing-an-account-sas)

Comment: I have verified with the owner of the account that this is an Account SAS key. They have also generated a new key with all services, resource types, and permissions. I still get 403. Do you know if we HAVE to have allowed IP addresses? We are assuming leaving blank means we do not have a white list.

Comment: @MattCash It totally can be a firewall or proxy issue, I'd recommend the following two suggestions: 
Allowing the URL *.blob.core.windows.net in Firewalls/proxies your customer has
a Testing scenario: 
Install Storage Explorer on the server you are trying to access the blobs from, and check if you get the same 403 errors or not, in addition, accessing it from a different network if possible as well. Let me know what the results are.

Comment: @MattCash Were you able to try out the above recommendations ?

Comment: I swear I answered this a few months back, apologies! Nothing worked unfortunately. The third party finally gave me the actual connection strings and all works as expected.